# unable to use $pullAll

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pull

I have a collection which contains the documents as shown below

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d92901f9d573cc1c1fb8bb"), 
    "busEntryExitInformation" : {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2016-03-04T06:19:45.914+0000"), 
        "busEntryExitEvent" : [
            {
                "plateNumber" : "ADFN3R2", 
                "direction" : "EXIT", 
                "routeNumber" : NumberInt(929), 
                "driverID" : "DId5", 
                "driverName" : "john", 
                "_id" : ObjectId("56d92901f9d573cc1c1fb8c0")
            }, 
            {
                "plateNumber" : "ADFN3R4", 
                "direction" : "EXIT", 
                "routeNumber" : NumberInt(652), 
                "driverID" : "DId2", 
                "driverName" : "jack", 
                "_id" : ObjectId("56d92901f9d573cc1c1fb8bf")
            }, 
            {
                "plateNumber" : "ADFN3R8", 
                "direction" : "EXIT", 
                "routeNumber" : NumberInt(500), 
                "driverID" : "DId5", 
                "driverName" : "john", 
                "_id" : ObjectId("56d92901f9d573cc1c1fb8be")
            }, 
            {
                "plateNumber" : "ADFN3R7", 
                "direction" : "ENTRY", 
                "routeNumber" : NumberInt(500), 
                "driverID" : "DId3", 
                "driverName" : "mack", 
                "_id" : ObjectId("56d92901f9d573cc1c1fb8bd")
            }, 
            {
                "plateNumber" : "ADFN3R2", 
                "direction" : "EXIT", 
                "routeNumber" : NumberInt(652), 
                "driverID" : "DId2", 
                "driverName" : "sandesh", 
                "_id" : ObjectId("56d92901f9d573cc1c1fb8bc")
            }
        ], 
        "cameraIntrinsics" : {
            "cameraFocalLength" : NumberInt(35), 
            "cameraAngle" : NumberInt(20), 
            "imageWidth" : "1920", 
            "imageHeight" : "1080", 
            "frameRate" : NumberInt(25)
        }, 
        "cameraExtrinsics" : {
            "cameraId" : NumberInt(1), 
            "cameraName" : "Under Route-090 NorthboundBridge", 
            "cameraDirection" : "Towards Northbound Lanes", 
            "cameraLatitude" : 1.350228, 
            "cameraLongitude" : 103.984889, 
            "cameraHeight" : NumberInt(30)
        }
    }, 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
}
```

where busEntryExitEvent is a array  i am trying to remove the array elements where direction is exit across all the documents in the collection 
result should contain all the documents with direction entry

```
  { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d92901f9d573cc1c1fb8bb"), 
        "busEntryExitInformation" : {
            "dateTime" : ISODate("2016-03-04T06:19:45.914+0000"), 
            "busEntryExitEvent" : [

                {
                    "plateNumber" : "ADFN3R7", 
                    "direction" : "ENTRY", 
                    "routeNumber" : NumberInt(500), 
                    "driverID" : "DId3", 
                    "driverName" : "mack", 
                    "_id" : ObjectId("56d92901f9d573cc1c1fb8bd")
                }
            ], 
            "cameraIntrinsics" : {
                "cameraFocalLength" : NumberInt(35), 
                "cameraAngle" : NumberInt(20), 
                "imageWidth" : "1920", 
                "imageHeight" : "1080", 
                "frameRate" : NumberInt(25)
            }, 
            "cameraExtrinsics" : {
                "cameraId" : NumberInt(1), 
                "cameraName" : "Under Route-090 NorthboundBridge", 
                "cameraDirection" : "Towards Northbound Lanes", 
                "cameraLatitude" : 1.350228, 
                "cameraLongitude" : 103.984889, 
                "cameraHeight" : NumberInt(30)
            }
        }, 
        "__v" : NumberInt(0)
    }
    }
```

i am trying to do like this

```
db.busEntryExitDoc.update(
      {  $pull: { busEntryExitEvent: {  "direction" : "EXIT"} } },
      { multi: false }
      )
```

this has to be done to all the documents there is no where condition  here how to do it please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MongoDB `update()` methods expects three arguments: `db.collection.update(query, update, options)`. If you want to perform the `update` on all documents, just use an empty object as `query`:

```
db.busEntryExitDoc.update({},
    { $pull: { 'busEntryExitInformation.busEntryExitEvent' : {'direction' : "EXIT"} } },
    { multi: true }
);
```

Also, note the use of the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to access the array field: you have to point the [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) operator to an array otherwise the operation fails. Finally, use `{ multi: true }` as [options](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) since you want to update all the documents in your collection.

Comment: that help me so much

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong the first argument to [`.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) is the "query" argument which should be an empty document here.

```js
db.busEntryExitDoc.update( 
    {},
    {  $pull: { "busEntryExitInformation.busEntryExitEvent": { "direction": "EXIT" }  } },
    {  multi: true }
)
```

The same thing apply to the [`.updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany) method

```js
db.busEntryExitDoc.update( 
    {},
    {  $pull: { "busEntryExitInformation.busEntryExitEvent":  { "direction": "EXIT" }  } },
)
```